# Margin property not working as expected

Tags: html, css

- Why cant I just use `margin-top:50%` and `margin:bottom:50%` on the classes `.logo` and `.right`to align them vertically

  According to what I've read `margin:bottom:50%` and `margin-top:50%` should automatically center vertically both`right` and `.logo` in their container `header` but rather they come to some random middle place of the page.

This is my main problem ( this weird margin behavior on window resize) 
- If I use  `margin-top:x%` and get them in vertically middle position of `header` then when I resize the window to small the LOGO shifts from being in middle of `header` to top.

```css
html {
  background-color: white
}
body {
  width: 88.5%;
  height: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #161e2c;
}
.top-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 153px;
  background-color: #314e59;
  border: 1px solid rgb(211, 41, 97);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 7.4px 2.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74);
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 23px 0 0 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 500%;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.right {
  margin-top: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  color: white
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="top-box">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Konoha</a>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

right now I am using `margin: (x) px` that's why they stay in middle even if i make the window smaller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

Comment: My main problem is different than the link you posted

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a border on an element you should use, the command, border-style instead.

`h2 {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-right-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
}`